# Optimize Synapse sql pool query

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I have this sql query on synapse sql pool, it joins 2 table one small table ([dbo].[Matrix]) that is distributed on replicate and one big table ([dbo].[Fact]) that I distributed as ROUND_ROBIN.
The query is very slow and I am searching for idea to optimize it (change the distribution of tables, change the query code...)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Fact]') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Fact]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fact]
WITH( DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX) AS
SELECT * 
FROM (
select 'acn1' as column1, 'cc1' as column2, 'mn1' as column3 union all
select 'acn2' , 'cc2' , 'mn2' union all
select 'acn1' , 'cc1' , NULL  union all
select 'acn1' , 'cc1' , 'mnx' union all
select 'acn3' , 'cc3' , NULL  ) T


IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[Matrix]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.[Matrix]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Matrix]
    WITH( DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN, CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX) AS
SELECT * 
FROM (
select 'acn1' as column1_include, 'cc1' as column2_include, NULL as column3_include, 
';mn1;mn5;' as column3_exclude , 1 as ID  union all
select 'acn2' , 'cc2' , 'mn2', NULL , 2   union all
select 'acn3' , 'cc3' , NULL , NULL , 3
) T


Select F.*, M.ID
FROM [dbo].[Fact] F
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Matrix] M 
ON COALESCE(M.column1_include, F.column1, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column1, '-1')
    AND COALESCE(M.column2_include, F.column2, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column2, '-1')
    AND COALESCE(M.column3_include, F.column3, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column3, '-1')
    AND ISNULL(PATINDEX('%;' +  F.column3  + ';%', M.column3_exclude), 0) = 0
```

Comment: ON COALESCE(M.column1_include, F.column1, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column1, '-1')
    AND COALESCE(M.column2_include, F.column2, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column2, '-1')
    AND COALESCE(M.column3_include, F.column3, '-1') = COALESCE(F.column3, '-1') this stuff is just horrible. It's probably better to do a lot of UNIONs where you specifically ask for what you want

Comment: @siggemannen How Can I change the COALESCE, I want the join condition to be ignored when the value on the [dbo].[Matrix] table is NULL.

Comment: The join condition is not sargable and will be forcing full index or table scans

Comment: @Stu any suggestion to avoid that ?

Comment: Yes, do some reseach on what sargable means, there's no end of good documentation. By using a function in your join condition the optimiser *must* evaluate the function for every row, throwing away any possibility of an index seek or range scan.